# What are the minimal legal requirements for a US LLC to hire a person as a subcontractor in India?

Tags: india, limited-liability-company

I have an LLC and am considering outsourcing some data entry work to India. The work itself is very simple, essentially do X tasks, get X dollars.

Assuming I can find a person in India willing to do this work, what legal documents are required for me to hire this person as a subcontractor? At the very least I assume I need a subcontractor agreement, but do I need to file any paperwork with either the US or Indian government? And who would be responsible for paying taxes etc?

Comment: Contractors are generally responsible for their own taxes.  You may have to file 1099 forms with the IRS to report the payments to the subcontractor; I don't know the rules for international payees, but I would be very surprised if the 1099 instructions do not say what you need to do.